# Faster retrieval of relationship properties in Neo4J graph database

Tags: performance, indexing, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

in my data model I take a statement of a user with hashtags, each hashtag is turned into a `node` and their co-occurrence is the `relationship` between them. For each relationship I need to take into account:

- the user who created it `rel.user` property
- the time it was created - `rel.timestamp` property
- the context it was created in - `rel.context` property
- the statement it was made in - `rel.statement` property

Now, Neo4J doesn't allow relationship property indexing and so when I do the search that requires me to retrieve and evaluate those properties, it takes a very long time. Specifically, when I do a Cypher request of the kind:

```
MERGE hashtag1-[rel:TO 
{context:"deb659c0-a18d-11e3-ace9-1fa4c6cf2894",
statement:"824acc80-aaa6-11e3-88e3-453baabaa7ed",
user:"b9745f70-a13f-11e3-98c5-476729c16049"}]->hashtag2 
ON CREATE 
SET 
rel.uid="824f6061-aaa6-11e3-88e3-453baabaa7ed",
rel.timestamp="13947117878770000";
```

This request first checks if there is a relationship with those properties and if there is, it won't do anything, but if there is none, it will add a new one (with a unique ID and timestamp). So then because evaluation of each relationship has to take place – and they are not indexed –  it takes a very long time for this request to go through. Now I'm having a problem with such request because I'm dealing with about 100 nodes and 300 relations at one query (the one above is only 1 type, there are also a few others added to the query but those above are the most expensive ones).

Therefore **the actual question:**

Does anybody know of a good way to keep those relationship properties and to somehow make them work faster, so they can be retrieved and evaluated when needed faster? Or do you think I should use a different type of request (if yes, which?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This almost looks to me as if you relationship should actually be a node, which then would be connected to nodes:

- context
- user
- statement
- tag1
- tag2
- tagN

Then you can have sensible merge options (.e.g merge on UID).

Currently you loose the power of the graph model for your relationships.

This is also discussed in the [graph-databases book](http://graphdatabases.com) in the chapter with the email domain.

Comment: Thank you, but what are my options without changing the model I use?

Comment: The thing is that yes, I could also change the graph model, but then it becomes unmanageable without the software – tools like internal Neo4J viz won't work because it already blocks everything when there's more than 20 nodes to display and in this case even to add 3 Concept nodes in 1 context within 1 statement with 1 user would require me to create at least 14 nodes with 28 relations. What if then I want to add 100 nodes in 1 context, with 1 statement and 1 user – I'll get a graph of like a thousands of nodes and even more edges just to represent that one thing...

Comment: The whole point of using Neo4J database (for me) is to have a way of recording data closer to the way it's displayed. If I start to create layers and layers of abstractions, I might as well go back to the good old MySQL - the write speed for a similar kind of problem is above is many times faster and the data structure is super simple: see http://textexture.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have your hashtag1 and hashtag2 nodes available?

And if so, **how many rels** already exist between these?

What Cypher has to do for this to work, is to go over **each of those** relationships and compare all 3 properties (which I'm not sure will fit into [shortstring storage](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/short-strings.html)) so they have to be loaded if they are not in the cache. You can check your store files, if you have a large string-store file then those uid's might not fit into the property records and have to be loaded separately.

What is the memory config of your server (heap and mmio)?

All that adds up.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm not sure how to check it but running java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize gives me ~500Mb initial heap size and ~800 max. But then my server's RAM is limited to 1GB for now. Is this what you were asking? [...] The hashtag1 and hashtag2 are created (or matched) earlier in the request with a MERGE operation. There can be anything from 3 (min, if the edge exists) to hundreds relations between them (in the future, as the DB grows).
[...] Where do I check the store files? [...] Thanks!

Comment: Please post your messages.log it contains the config and memory usage and store-file-size information.